# I tried to make flutter web and i have issue with profile picuture when i picked image it doesn't display

Tags: flutter, image, web, picker

The profile page is loading fine but as soon as I click the camera or galley icon, it opening the desktop.
Once I pick image it doesn't appear on the profile image section but I am not able to fix it yet. terminal doesn't shows any error.
Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/Landing.page.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/Provider/user.provider.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/learner/Screens/others/learner_favourites.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/learner/utils/LearnerColors.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/learner/utils/LearnerConstant.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/learner/utils/learner_images.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/learner/utils/learner_strings.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/main/utils/app_widget.dart';
import 'package:nb_utils/src/extensions/widget_extensions.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/leaderboard.screen.dart';
import 'package:learningapp/edit.login.details.screen.dart';

class LearnerProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const LearnerProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LearnerProfileState createState() => _LearnerProfileState();
}

class _LearnerProfileState extends State<LearnerProfile> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    AppUser();
  }

  PickedFile? imageFile = null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    changeStatusColor(learner_layout_background);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: learner_layout_background,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 16, right: 16),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(color: learner_white, width: 4)),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _showPicker(context);
                            },
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              //backgroundImage: const AssetImage(learner_ic_Profile),
                              radius: 55,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                              child: imageFile != null
                                  ? ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                      child: Image.file(
                                        File(imageFile!.path),
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 100,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 100,
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.camera_alt,
                                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                                      )),
                            ))),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        text(AppUser.instance.user!.displayName,
                            fontFamily: fontSemibold,
                            fontSize: textSizeLargeMedium,
                            textColor: learner_textColorPrimary),
                        text(learner_lbl_390_290_points,
                            textColor: learner_textColorPrimary),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            learnerAward(
                                learner_ic_medal, learner_colorPrimary),
                            learnerAward(learner_ic_crown, learner_green),
                            learnerAward(learner_ic_cup, learner_light_pink),
                            learnerAward(learner_ic_flag, learner_orange_dark),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 16),
                  child: text(learner_lbl_general,
                      fontFamily: fontBold,
                      textAllCaps: true,
                      textColor: learner_textColorPrimary)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: boxDecoration(
                    bgColor: learner_white, showShadow: true, radius: 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: learnerOption(
                        learner_ic_heart,
                        learner_lbl_favourite_courses,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LearnerFavourites()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    /* InkWell(
                    //   child: learnerOption(
                    //       learner_ic_user, learner_lbl_my_friends),
                    //   onTap: () {
                    //     Navigator.push(
                    //       context,
                    //       MaterialPageRoute(
                    //           builder: (context) => LearnerMyFriends()),
                    //     );
                    //   },
                    // ),*/
                    InkWell(
                      child: learnerOption(
                          learner_ic_achievements, lbl_leaderboard),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LeaderboardScreen()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 16),
                  child: text(learner_lbl_settings,
                      fontFamily: fontBold,
                      textAllCaps: true,
                      textColor: learner_textColorPrimary)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: boxDecoration(
                    bgColor: learner_white, showShadow: true, radius: 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      child: learnerOption(
                          learner_ic_key, learner_lbl_edit_login_details),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => EditLoginDetailsScreen()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    learnerOption(
                        learner_ic_correct, learner_lbl_update_interests),
                    // learnerOption(learner_ic_block, learner_lbl_blocked_users),
                    InkWell(
                      child: learnerOption(learner_ic_logout, 'Logout'),
                      onTap: () async {
                        await AppUser.instance.signOut();
                        LoadingPage().launch(context);
                        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
                        print("logout");
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showPicker(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              child: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                      title: Text('Photo Library'),
                      onTap: () {
                        _openGallery(context);
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      }),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                    title: Text('Camera'),
                    onTap: () {
                      _openCamera(context);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget learnerAward(var icon, var bgColor) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      width: 35,
      height: 35,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: bgColor),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Image.asset(
          icon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget learnerOption(var icon, var heading) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 10, 16, 8),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: boxDecoration(
                    bgColor: learner_white, radius: 8, showShadow: true),
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  icon,
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 16,
              ),
              text(heading,
                  textColor: learner_textColorPrimary,
                  fontSize: textSizeLargeMedium,
                  fontFamily: fontSemibold),
            ],
          ),
          const Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
            color: learner_textColorSecondary,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

//pick from gallery
  void _openGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    setState(() {
      imageFile = pickedFile! as PickedFile?;
    });

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  //pick from camera
  void _openCamera(BuildContext context) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );
    setState(() {
      imageFile = pickedFile! as PickedFile?;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml
image_picker: ^0.8.4+4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Flutter web default use canvaskit renderer so sometimes a problem to load images so try with "flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html".

Comment: i can pick up a pic but it doesn't shows on the pic section    https://ibb.co/TrN7LrJ

Comment: https://ibb.co/TrN7LrJ    I tried its work. Check on the answer I placed a screenshot.